# ODE system with 3x3 matrix.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have this ODE system:
$$X'=AX$$

$$A=   \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    -2 & 1 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}   $$

I have to find all the solutions $X$.

I have founded the eigenvalues of this matrix by using the Laplace method and the Ruffini theorem to scompose the resulting third order equation.

So, the eigenvalues for $A$ are:
$$\lambda_{1}=2$$
$$\lambda_{2,3}=\pm i$$

So, I'm expecting something like that for the solutions:
$$c_1e^{2t}\mathbf u+c_2e^{0}[\mathbf v\cos(t)-\mathbf w\sin(t)]$$

---

Now I have founded the eigenvector $\mathbf u$ for $\lambda_1$. Noting that $rg(A-2I)=2$ I just consider, for example, two lines:
$$x-y+z=0$$
$$-2x+y-3z=0$$

So I have

$$y=-\frac{5}{2}x$$
$$x=2$$
$$z=-3$$

So,
$$\mathbf u=\begin{pmatrix}
    2\\
    -5\\
    -3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}  $$

---

I have more troubles with $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$

$$\det(A-iI)=\det   \begin{pmatrix}
    1-i & -1 & 1 \\
    0 & 2-i & 0 \\
    -2 & 1 & -1-i \\
    \end{pmatrix}   $$
Which is a 3x3 matrix with $rg=3$.
So I have to consider all the lines and solve the corresponding system to find the result.
Moreover, since the eigenvalues are complex and coniugated, I think that it's enough this matrix to find the solution.

What do you think about that? Any hint to simplify the finding of $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$? Thank you very much.

Comment: The RREF for $\lambda = 2$ of $[A - 2 I]v_1 = 0$, is $$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & \dfrac{2}{3} \\
 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{5}{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} v_1 = 0$$ An eigenvector is $v_1 = (-2, 5, 3)$.

Comment: The rank of $A-iI$ is 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $(A-2I)v_1=0$, you can easily obtain
$$ v_1=(-2,5,3)^T. $$
Letting $(A-iI)x=0$, you can easily obtain
$$ x=(-1-i,0,2)^T=v_2+iv_3, v_2=(-1,0,-2),v_3=(-1,0,0). $$
So the general solution is
$$ X=c_1e^{2t}v_1+c_2(v_2\cos t-v_3\sin t)+c_3(v_3\cos t+v_2\sin t)$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have understood my mistake that I have corrected. I also found the solution on my problem. Thank you for the support. :).